# How to fetch exact matching records in Spring JPA @Query

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities

**1. Request**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "request")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Request {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "requestId", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private Collection<Service> services;
}
```

**2. Service**

```
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "service")
@JsonIgnoreProperties({"hibernateLazyInitializer", "handler"})
public class Service{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "request_id")
    private Integer requestId;

    @Column(name = "status")
    private String status;
}
```

Now, to fetch **requests** having **service(s)** of specific **status** I wrote following **@Query** in **RequestDao** file.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT req FROM request req JOIN req.services srvs WHERE (srvs.status = :serviceStatus)")
List<Request> getAll(@Param("serviceStatus") String serviceStatus)
```

As result, I'm getting all services inside the 'request' object if any of the associated service matches the 'where' criteria.. while I'm expecting 'request' to only include those services which are matching with 'where' criteria.

Can anyone please help?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

That's not so easy because Hibernate/JPA try to guarantee that the entity model is in sync with the database state. You apparently want a projection that most probably should not be kept in sync with the database. If you really must do this, you can use the following query, but beware that this might cause deletion of service elements in the collection that don't match the criteria:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT req FROM request req JOIN FETCH req.services srvs WHERE (srvs.status = :serviceStatus)")
List<Request> getAll(@Param("serviceStatus") String serviceStatus);
```

This is usually handled by introducing DTOs and I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Request.class)
public interface RequestDto {
    @IdMapping
    Integer getId();
    String getStatus();
    @Mapping("services[status = :serviceStatus]")
    Set<ServiceDto> getServices();

    @EntityView(Service.class)
    interface ServiceDto {
        @IdMapping
        Integer getId();
        Integer getRequestId();
        String getStatus();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`RequestDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, RequestDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
List<RequestDto> findAll(@OptionalParam("serviceStatus") String serviceStatus);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!

Comment: Thanks @christian, but I cannot use projection as my entities contain lots of columns and further deep relationships that I'll need to project as well. I'm just wondering why JPA returns all records when I'm mentioning the criteria, is there any better way to handle it?

Comment: So what, then create DTOs for the nested relationships as well? Like I wrote, you can use `JOIN FETCH` to tell Hibernate, that the join should be used to initialize the association, but beware that this could lead to deletions because Hibernate tries to keep the entity objects in sync with the database. If you don't alter the collection, you could be lucky and no delete happens, but if you really must use this approach, I would suggest you immediately detach the entity after retrieval to avoid issues.

Comment: It seems the only safe solution is to remove non-related items manually by applying the foreach loop and check for the status match...

Answer (score -1):

Try updating your query to:

```java
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT req FROM request req LEFT JOIN req.services srvs WHERE (srvs.status = :serviceStatus)")
List<Request> getAll(@Param("serviceStatus") String serviceStatus)
```