# Subsequent query execution in JPA

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Let's assume there is a class named Person with following structure in spring boot

```
@Entity
class Person {
    Long id;
    String name;
    @OneToMany
    Set<PhoneNumber> phoneNumbers;
}
```

Person consists of set of phone numbers.

```
@Entity
class PhoneNumber {
    Long id;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinByColumn("person_id")
    Person person;
    String category;
    String mobileNumber;
    String phoneNumber;
}
```

`PhoneNumber` is a class which consists of above fields where category represents `mobile` or `phone` etc.

```
class PersonRepository extends JPARepository<Person, Long> {
     Person findById(Long id);
}
```

So, whenever I want to fetch `Person` details with some `id`, I will call the above method `findById` , then it should fetch `Person` details along with `phoneNumbers` whose `category` is `mobile`.

The approach should be whenever it executes query internally for the `findById` method, it should execute subsequent query for fetching `PhoneNumber` whose category is `mobile`.
Is there any way I can get it as mentioned above or is there any other approach for achieving it? Please let me know.

PS: If there are any issues or errors in my way of asking please comment below. It will help me.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your question. Do you want to get the mobile number of a person with a given id? So do you want the query to return the person first and then get the mobile number(s)? Or do you want the query to only return a person if there is at least one mobile number? Or do you want the query to return the person and all associated mobile numbers in one request?

Comment: I want the query to return the `person` and all the associated phone numbers whose `category` is mobile.

Comment: i think this is what you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/q/66435595/2683501 but this is very dangerous. Maybe you should do this the other way around and ask the  PhoneNumber  table give me every entry with this `person` and this `category`

Comment: Well, you can't filter the set inside `Person` since that could break JPA but you could load The cartesian product of person and numbers via a join (like `SELECT p, n FROM Person p JOIN p.phoneNumbers n ...`). But why not load all phone numbers and filter in code (just don't change the set itself)? Or load the numbers in a separate query?

Comment: @Thomas, even i thought of filtering it in the code, but i just wanted to know whether there is any approach to do it just by using JPA

Comment: @pL4Gu33, the other way is a good one. I'm trying it. What if I don't have the person id's and I only have the People id's which is mapped with person id's?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it. Refer this:

Repo:

```java
class PersonRepository extends JPARepository<Person, Long>,JpaSpecificationExecutor<Post> {
     Person findById(Long id);
}
```

```java
    public static Specification<Person> search(Long id) {
        return ((root, criteriaQuery, criteriaBuilder) -> {
            criteriaQuery.distinct(true);
            return criteriaBuilder.and(
                    criteriaBuilder.equal(root.get("id"), id),
                    criteriaBuilder.equal(root.join("phone_number").get("category"), "mobile")
           );
        });
    }
```

```java
personRepo.findAll(search(10));
```

Comment: https://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-specifications

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method-

```
// method in Person entity class
public static List<Person> findByIdMobile(long id, String category) {
  return find("id = ?1 and  phoneNumbers.category = ?2", id, category).list();
}

// can use this as
List<Person> mobilePersons = Person.findByIdMobile(1234,"mobile");
```